# How to integrate quickblox into xcode 7

Tags: ios, xcode7, quickblox

I tried to integrate quickblox including the framework, QMService and QMMessenger but I failed. I cannot run QuickBlox iOS Sample Chat example either. I am using cocoapods and xcode 7.

Comment: Have you tried http://quickblox.com/developers/SimpleSample-chat_users-ios ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Latest QuickBlox iOS SDK 2.4.4 is fully compatible with Xcode7 and Swift2

http://quickblox.com/developers/IOS#Framework_changelog:

Comment: @cjmemory great! you can mark this answer as correct